# How can I set the response code from the DataPersister

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm working with Symfony 4.4 / API Platform, and I'm trying to return the response from the DataPersister or to set up its code.

In my DataPersister, I test if the Admin->isManager() is true, So Admin can never be deleted, So in this case I want to return a custom status code in my response 414, and a message "thisAdminIsManager"

## AdminDataPersister:

```
final class AdminDataPersister implements ContextAwareDataPersisterInterface
{
    /* @var EntityManagerInterface */
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $manager
    ){
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }


    public function supports($data, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return $data instanceof Admin;
    }

    public function persist($data, array $context = [])
    {   
        $this->manager->persist($data);
        $this->manager->flush();
    }

    public function remove($data, array $context = [])
    {
        /* @var Admin $data */
        #The Manager can never be deleted:
        if( $data->getManager() ){
            return; //here I want to return the custom response
        }
        $this->manager->remove($data);
        $this->manager->flush();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should throw an exception, then you should configurate your api_platform to handle this exception. ApiPlatform will convert exception into a response with message and the specified code.

**Step1:** Create dedicated exception class

```php
<?php
// api/src/Exception/ProductNotFoundException.php

namespace App\Exception;

final class AdminNonDeletableException extends \Exception
{
}
```

**Step2:** In your data persister, throw exception:

```php
    public function remove($data, array $context = [])
    {
        /* @var Admin $data */
        #The Manager can never be deleted:
        if( $data->getManager() ){
            throw new AdminNonDeletableException('thisAdminIsManager');
        }
        $this->manager->remove($data);
        $this->manager->flush();

    }
```

**Step3:** Add your exception in the config/package/api_platform.yaml file and declare the code number (414)

```yaml
# config/packages/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    # ...
    exception_to_status:
        # The 4 following handlers are registered by default, keep those lines to prevent unexpected side effects
        Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\ExceptionInterface: 400 # Use a raw status code (recommended)
        ApiPlatform\Core\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: !php/const Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        ApiPlatform\Core\Exception\FilterValidationException: 400
        Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException: 409

        # Custom mapping
        App\Exception\AdminNonDeletableException: 414 # Here is the handler for your custom exception associated to the 414 code
```

You can find more information in [error handling chapter](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/errors/#converting-php-exceptions-to-http-errors)

Comment: At first, it's the second time that you answer my question, I want to thank you very much. Second, Yes that's work but the Http Response content contains my trace from AdminDataPersister to AppKernel .. So I create a response listener and I set my content message. Thank you @Alexandre.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not sure to understand, but tThe trace won't appear in production environment.